# How to get items from an array in a different .m file?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I have an array of 6 `NSNumber`'s in a file called `level.m`. In another file, `game.m`, I would like to 'get' this array and change each of its objects to separate integers.

I have tried using `NSUserDefaults`, but that seems to be a very awkward way of doing what I want to do. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a much better way than using NSUserDefaults!

You can simply access the array directly from your game.m. First, you must import the level.h into the game.m (like so: `#import "level.h"`).

Now say you want to int the value of the number at index 0 in your array. you can do that as follows: `int myNumber = [[[name_of_level_class name_of_array] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];`

A quick `NSLog` will prove that the `myNumber` integer will be equal to whatever number you have at your 0 index in the array in your level.m

Answer (score -1):

Add your array into AppDelegate and it will be able to access globally throughout application.

Create property and synthesize your array in AppDelegate.

You can use anwhere u want using AppDelegate 's instance

Comment: This is not the correct way to do this. The app delegate is responsible for setting up the root view controller and adding it to the main window. Beyond that, you should **seriously** consider what you put into your app delegate. It is **not** a place to store general use variables - this is bad practice and quickly leads to spaghetti code and possibly performance issues. If you **really** need an object/variable to be accessible globally, consider a **singleton** pattern, but even then, use this sparingly.

Comment: @JRG-Developer  app delegate is heart of application. I agree with u but my idea is perfect check [this](http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/8/passing-data-between-view-controllers-in-objective-c.html). Also u will find more in google.